# duration for a signal after filtering

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, digital-communications

I have a signal $s(t)$ of duration $T$. This signal doesn't have a limited bandwidth. To solve this problem, I filter it with a pulse shaping filter (raised cosine filter).

My question:
Does filtering change the duration of the signal?

Answer (score 1):

A classical result states that a (non-trivial)  time-limited signal does not have a  limited bandwidth (in terms of support). The converse happens as well: a bandwidth-limited signal cannot be of finite length.

And there is a similar rule-of-thumb principle:  when you try to reduce the support of a signal in one domain (time or frequency), you generally spread it in the other domain.